# list from java class is not getting passed to jsp

Tags: java, list, jsp, for-loop

In my Java class.

```
  List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
  values.add(ssn);
  values.add(firstName);
  values.add(lastName);
  values.add(address);
   request.setAttribute("databaseList", values);

    request.getRequestDispatcher("/FormDemo.jsp").forward(request,response);
```

Here is teh formDemo.jsp page

```
  <html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
 <title>Login Form</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="application.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
<body>
<div align="center">
    <div class="header"></div>
    <div class="mainbody">

     Job Category: <select name="database1">
            <c:forEach items="${databaseList}" var="databaseValue">
                <option value="${databaseValue}">${databaseValue}</option>
                <c:forEach>
        </select>

    </div>
</div>

 </body>
</html>
```

please correct me where i am going wrong, i can see the drop box but with no values in it.My list as all four values of type String but still it is not populating the values in jsp.

Comment: How do we know that your four variables aren't blank to begin with?

Comment: @tom Did u get select box with four empty values or select box itself empty

Comment: @Takendarkk -  i have values in them, I assigned them manually.

Comment: @SivaKumar - select box its self empty

Comment: @tom Can u please attach the entire jsp

Comment: Is your JSP even evaluating? Show the generated HTML.

Comment: @SivaKumar - Here is my jsp page<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Login Form</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="application.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
 <div align="center">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div class="mainbody">

Job Category: <select name="database1">
    <c:forEach items="${databaseList}" var="databaseValue">
     <option value="${databaseValue}">${databaseValue}</option>
     <c:forEach>
   </select>

  </div>
 </div>

</body>
</html>

Comment: @DaveNewton yes my html is evaluating

Comment: Show the resulting HTML.

Comment: @tom Did you include c tag library in you jsp.

Answer (score 0):

In your JSP try:

```
<c:forEach items="${requestScope.databaseList}" var="databaseValue">
```

Edit...

I just re-read your post, are you getting blank values in your dropdown? If so, you should double-check that the Strings you are putting in the list are not null or blank.

Comment: if i print just ${databaseList} it is diaplaying all the list values

Comment: OK, try to use c:out for the values you want to output to the browser: <option value="<c:out value="${databaseValue}" />"><c:out value="${databaseValue}" /></option>